# Usage of `disconnectedActivitySid` on `Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker()`

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

From the [latest doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js#taskrouterworker) on `Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker` I found there's a parameter on `Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker()` function as `disconnectedActivitySid`, which is explained as:

> (optional) ActivitySid to place the worker in upon the Websocket Disconnecting

I'm trying to push the worker of Twilio Taskrouter to Offline activity when a user closes the corresponding webpage, so I set up this parameter as the acitivitySid of `Offline`, but then I get a unstable result about that.

There would be about 40% of the cases that, when I closed the webpage, the worker was not pushed to Offline state.

Wondering if this `disconnectedActivitySid` is registering a listener on Twilio Server to see if the websocket disconnected, or is it firing a event from client side on websocket disconnection? If it is firing events from client-side, then what would be a stable solution for handling sudden disconnections so that the workers could be immediately pushed to Offline via Twilio's way?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I don't know the answer to this, so I'm investigating this internally and will let you know what I find out.

Comment: @philnash OK thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently the TaskRouter JS fires that event client side, which is why it is not 100% stable. There is a plan to improve that, but in the meantime, this is what we suggest:

1. The [Twilio Sync service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/) currently includes a reachability feature that is controlled by the Twilio backend. Add the Sync SDK to your app, and issue tokens with the Sync grant as well as TaskRouter grants.
2. Enable [Reachability Webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/webhooks#reachability-events) on that Sync instance. These are sent by the Twilio backend.
3. Whenever you get an `endpoint_disconnected` event:

   a) correlate it with a ceremonious departure (your app was able to disconnect gracefully) and do nothing;

   b) correlate it with a reconnection by the same endpoint (to handle slight blips in connectivity) and do nothing; or

   c) after a timeout (10s?), mark the user disconnected from your backend.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer helps a lot! I didn't noticed `Twilio.Sync` before :)

Comment: No worries, hope it goes well for you!

Comment: From [Reachability Webhooks docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/webhooks#reachability-events):
_Note: Sync is rebalancing connections every hour, which also triggers the endpoint_disconnected -> endpoint_connected cycle as a side effect._
So it is definitely a timeout check needed (step 3c).
Also Twilio Sync is paid service.